# Need a work around on this WSDL to get rid of import element

Tags: wsdl, import, tag, issue

```
    <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">

            <sp:SamlToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">

                <wsp:Policy>

                    <sp:WssSamlV11Token10/>

                </wsp:Policy>

            </sp:SamlToken>

        </wsp:Policy>

    </sp:SupportingTokens>

</WL5G3N1:Policy>
```

-->

```
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N3="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:WL5G3N4="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay" xmlns:WL5G3N5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:WL5G3N6="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:WL5G3N7="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:log="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:oagis="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd1="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:xsd2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay">
        <xsd:element name="PublishProcessvoiceMessageResponse">

            <xsd:complexType>

                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element name="STATUS" type="xsd:string"/>

                </xsd:sequence>

            </xsd:complexType>

        </xsd:element>

    </xsd:schema>

    <xsd:schema namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" schemaLocation="http://sfdc3-osb-dit.us.shered.com:80/sfdc/voice/Services?SCHEMA%2Fsfdcvoice%2F1_0%2FXMLSchema%2Ftypes%2FOAGIS%2FProcessvoice" targetNamespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N3="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:WL5G3N4="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay" xmlns:WL5G3N5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:WL5G3N6="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:WL5G3N7="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:log="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:oagis="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd1="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:xsd2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay">

       <!-- <xsd:import namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" schemaLocation="http://sfdc3-osb-dit.us.shered.com:80/sfdc/voice/Services?SCHEMA%2Fsfdcvoice%2F1_0%2FXMLSchema%2Ftypes%2FOAGIS%2FProcessvoice"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" schemaLocation="http://sfdc3-osb-dit.us.shered.com:80/sfdc/voice/Services?SCHEMA%2Fsfdcvoice%2F1_0%2FXMLSchema%2FSearchBycntrXMLS"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay" schemaLocation="http://sfdc3-osb-dit.us.shered.com:80/sfdc/voice/Services?SCHEMA%2Fsfdcvoice%2F1_0%2FXMLSchema%2FUpdateToPayXMLS"/>

    --></xsd:schema>

    <xsd:schema namespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" schemaLocation="http://sfdc3-osb-dit.us.shered.com:80/sfdc/voice/Services?SCHEMA%2Fsfdcvoice%2F1_0%2FXMLSchema%2FSearchBycntrXMLS" targetNamespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N3="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:WL5G3N4="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay" xmlns:WL5G3N5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:WL5G3N6="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:WL5G3N7="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:log="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:oagis="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd1="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:xsd2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay"/>
    <xsd:schema namespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay" schemaLocation="http://sfdc3-osb-dit.us.shered.com:80/sfdc/voice/Services?SCHEMA%2Fsfdcvoice%2F1_0%2FXMLSchema%2FUpdateToPayXMLS" targetNamespace="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:WL5G3N3="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:WL5G3N4="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay" xmlns:WL5G3N5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:WL5G3N6="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:WL5G3N7="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:log="http://shelter.com/sfdc/GIL/sfdcLogging/1_0" xmlns:oagis="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd1="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr" xmlns:xsd2="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay"/>

</WL5G3N0:types>

<WL5G3N0:message name="PublishProcessvoiceMessageMsgIn">

    <WL5G3N0:part name="request" element="WL5G3N3:Processvoice"/>

</WL5G3N0:message>

<WL5G3N0:message name="PublishProcessvoiceMessageOut">

    <WL5G3N0:part name="response" element="WL5G3N4:PublishProcessvoiceMessageResponse"/>

</WL5G3N0:message>
<WL5G3N0:message name="SearchBycntrRequest">
    <WL5G3N0:part name="parameters" element="WL5G3N5:SearchBycntrRequest"/>
</WL5G3N0:message>
<WL5G3N0:message name="SearchBycntrResponse">
    <WL5G3N0:part name="parameters" element="WL5G3N5:SearchBycntrResponse"/>
</WL5G3N0:message>
<WL5G3N0:message name="UpdateToPayRequest">
    <WL5G3N0:part name="parameters" element="WL5G3N6:UpdateToPayRequest"/>
</WL5G3N0:message>
<WL5G3N0:message name="UpdateToPayResponse">
    <WL5G3N0:part name="parameters" element="WL5G3N6:UpdateToPayResponse"/>
</WL5G3N0:message>
<WL5G3N0:portType name="sfdcvoicePortType">
    <WL5G3N0:operation name="PublishProcessvoiceMessage">
        <WL5G3N0:input message="WL5G3N4:PublishProcessvoiceMessageMsgIn"/>
        <WL5G3N0:output message="WL5G3N4:PublishProcessvoiceMessageOut"/>
    </WL5G3N0:operation>
    <WL5G3N0:operation name="SearchBycntr">
        <WL5G3N0:input message="WL5G3N4:SearchBycntrRequest"/>
        <WL5G3N0:output message="WL5G3N4:SearchBycntrResponse"/>
    </WL5G3N0:operation>
    <WL5G3N0:operation name="UpdateToPay">
        <WL5G3N0:input message="WL5G3N4:UpdateToPayRequest"/>
        <WL5G3N0:output message="WL5G3N4:UpdateToPayResponse"/>
    </WL5G3N0:operation>
</WL5G3N0:portType>
<WL5G3N0:binding name="sfdcvoiceSOAP" type="WL5G3N4:sfdcvoicePortType">
    <WL5G3N1:Policy>
        <WL5G3N1:PolicyReference URI="#wss10_saml_token_service_policy"/>
    </WL5G3N1:Policy>
    <WL5G3N7:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <WL5G3N0:operation name="PublishProcessvoiceMessage">
        <WL5G3N7:operation soapAction="PublishProcessvoiceMessage"/>
        <WL5G3N0:input>
            <WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N8:HeaderSoap" part="request_header" use="literal"/>
            <WL5G3N7:body use="literal"/>
        </WL5G3N0:input>
        <WL5G3N0:output>
            <WL5G3N7:body use="literal"/>
        </WL5G3N0:output>
    </WL5G3N0:operation>
    <WL5G3N0:operation name="SearchBycntr">
        <WL5G3N7:operation soapAction="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/SearchBycntr"/>
        <WL5G3N0:input>
            <WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N8:HeaderSoap" part="request_header" use="literal"/>
            <WL5G3N7:body use="literal"/>
        </WL5G3N0:input>
        <WL5G3N0:output>
            <WL5G3N7:body use="literal"/>
        </WL5G3N0:output>
    </WL5G3N0:operation>
    <WL5G3N0:operation name="UpdateToPay">
        <WL5G3N7:operation soapAction="http://shelter.com/sfdc/voice/UpdateToPay"/>
        <WL5G3N0:input>
            <WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N8:HeaderSoap" part="request_header" use="literal"/>
            <WL5G3N7:body use="literal"/>
        </WL5G3N0:input>
        <WL5G3N0:output>
            <WL5G3N7:body use="literal"/>
        </WL5G3N0:output>
    </WL5G3N0:operation>
</WL5G3N0:binding>
<WL5G3N0:service name="sfdcvoiceSOAPQSService">
    <WL5G3N0:port name="sfdcvoiceSOAPQSPort" binding="WL5G3N4:sfdcvoiceSOAP">
        <WL5G3N7:address location="http://sfdc3-osb-dit.us.shered.com:80/sfdc/voice/Services"/>
    </WL5G3N0:port>
</WL5G3N0:service>
```

Comment: Can you share the full WSDL path? I've made a free [tool](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) that can create the Apex classes with direct support for xsd:import. So you don't need to muck around flattening the WSDL.

Comment: Due to Company polocies I cannot expose the complete WSDl Daniel so I modified this partially placed WSDL too.

Comment: that's fine. Can you use our free tool to process the WSDL? It will handle the import for you. If you can use the Windows desktop version the WSDL will never leave your machine.

Comment: I used Windows desktop version and I am getting this error. which I updated in the question

Comment: Is that the URL where the WSDL is stored? If you can't get to it with a web browser then the tool won't be able to send a GET request for it.

Comment: that url is part of wsdl and When I commented  the import tags and created the 3 <schema> tags and copy pasted the 3 import attributes namespace and schema location into each one of the schema tags even then I got the same issue which i shown in the image.

Comment: Have you checked that all your `xsd:schema` elements have a targetNamespace attribute defined? I see the second one in your question doesn't

Comment: Even after adding the targetname space to all schema tags it is thorwing the same error.

Comment: Without access to the complete WSDL, including imports, it will be **really** difficult to guide you through manually flattening the WSDL. I've got [some general tips](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/03/consuming-aspnet-web-service-from.html). However, fixing your specific issues probably isn't going to be realistic here without a lot more information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30330/discussion-between-suri-and-daniel-ballinger).